# An example that the Galois correspondence fails if the extensions is not Galois

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F/K$ be a finite extension of fields. $S$ the set of subgroups of $\mathrm{Aut}_K(F)$ and $I$ the set of intermediate fields of the extension $F/K$. Define the function $\varphi:S\rightarrow I$ as $\varphi(G)= F^G$ where $F_G$ is the subfield of $F$ fixed by $G$. Could you help me to find an example of extension $F/K$ where $\varphi$ is not surjective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$K=\mathbb{Q}$, $F=K(\sqrt[4]{2})$, $G$ is the group oforder two.

There are 2 subgroups and 3 intermediate fields ($K$, $F$, and $K(\sqrt{2})$).